# Drawing items at selected grid locations

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

I would like to draw a grid and place queens are selected columns for each row. I am able to draw the grid, but the placement of queens is improper.

```
\makeatletter\newcommand{\showQL}[3][,]{%
  \def\row{#2}\def\negOne{-1}
  \def\dolist##1{\expandafter\@dolist##1#1\@eol}%
  \def\@dolist##1#1##2#1##3\@eol{%
    \ifx\negOne##2\else\draw node at ($(##1,##2)+(45:.75)$) {\symqueen};\fi
    \ifx\@eol##3\@eol\else\@dolist##2+1#1##3\@eol\fi}%
  \dolist{#2,#3}%
}\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \def\xMin{0}\def\xMax{5}\def\yMin{0}\def\yMax{5}
 \foreach\i in {\xMin,...,\xMax}{\draw[very thin,gray] (\i,\yMin)--(\i,\yMax);}
 \foreach\i in {\yMin,...,\yMax}{\draw[very thin,gray] (\xMin,\i)--(\xMax,\i);}
 \showQL{5}{-1,3,2,1,4,5}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please give us complete code for a minimal example we can compile. This should start with `\documentclass...` and end `\end{document}`. It should include just those packages required for your example to work. Right now the best anybody could do is guess. Also, if your code is based on a previous post, please provide a link as this site's search function sucks.

Comment: What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: If you use `\symqueen` then you probably already load the `skak` or `xskak` package, so maybe you can just draw the queens on a 5x5 chess board using those packages?